# File does not end with a newline [NewlineAtEndOfFile]

Tags: java, eclipse, file, newline, checkstyle

When trying to use mvn clean install on my project I'm getting those errors:

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\lob\Downloads\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\parent\eclipse-code-formatter-js.xml:0: File does not end with a newline. [NewlineAtEndOfFile]
[ERROR] C:\Users\lob\Downloads\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\parent\eclipse-code-formatter.xml:0: File does not end with a newline. [NewlineAtEndOfFile]
[ERROR] C:\Users\lob\Downloads\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\parent\pom.xml:0: File does not end with a newline. [NewlineAtEndOfFile]
[ERROR] C:\Users\lob\Downloads\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\parent\README.txt:0: File does not end with a newline. [NewlineAtEndOfFile]
Audit done.
[INFO] There are 4 errors reported by Checkstyle 7.2 with zanata-build-tools/checkstyle.xml ruleset.
[ERROR] eclipse-code-formatter-js.xml:[0] (misc) NewlineAtEndOfFile: File does not end with a newline.
[ERROR] eclipse-code-formatter.xml:[0] (misc) NewlineAtEndOfFile: File does not end with a newline.
[ERROR] pom.xml:[0] (misc) NewlineAtEndOfFile: File does not end with a newline.
[ERROR] README.txt:[0] (misc) NewlineAtEndOfFile: File does not end with a newline.
```

Putting paragraphs or \n at the end of those files does not solve this issue. 
In Eclipse under     `Window >> Preferences >> Checkstyle >> Select the configuration file >>` those files aren't listed.

Using:

- Windows 10
- Java 8
- Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1)
- Maven 3.0.4

Comment: Edit: It's a Linux project

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr:**

1. run `git config core.autocrlf true`
2. remove all files and folders other than `.git`
3. run `git reset --hard HEAD`

**detail and root cause:**

1. Git line ending config

   Git configuration on Windows is the root cause of this error. `zanata-platform-platform` which is built with Unix style line ending. In windows, maven will misunderstands Unix style line ending `LF` as improper Windows line ending `CRLF`.

   First step is to re-configure git installed on Windows so that when git generate file replacing `LF` to `CRLF`. On Windows, you edit files with `CRLF` but this config tells git to convert `CRLF` to `LF` when you commit or push.
2. Delete all files while keeping `.git` directory which contains history
3. Let git newly generate files with Windows style line ending.

Comment: Thats the case, but I think it's more likely to be the checkstyle bug. All Windows applications I use know about LF endings and treat them correctly, so I switched autocrlf to false. Now that checkstyle behavior... BTW it is configurable with `NewlineAtEndOfFile` module property: `<property name="lineSeparator" value="lf"/>`, but I would prefer automatic recognition.

Answer (score 2):

The cause is a **checkstyle rule** called `NewlineAtEndOfFile` which prevents a successful build if any of the project's files does not have a new line at its end.

The rule says:

> Rationale: Any source files and text files in general should end with
>   a line separator to let other easily add new content at the end of
>   file and "diff" command does not show previous lines as changed.

So what must be done, is simply to add a new line at the end of each of the files mentioned in the above logs:

. eclipse-code-formatter-js.xml

. eclipse-code-formatter.xml

. pom.xml

. README.txt

For more infos on this rule: [checkstyle-NewlineAtEndOfFile-rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#NewlineAtEndOfFile)